Sonar detects "useless assignment to local variable" (S1854) for dubious reasons
Using Java 17, sonar detects 3 Code Smells

Remove this useless assignment to local variable attrs.
Remove this useless assignment to local variable ac.
Remove this useless assignment to local variable map.

in the following code:
Map<String, String> attrs = tag.getAttributes();
String name = attrs.get("name");

if (propertyFilter.stream().anyMatch(name::matches)) {
    AttributesContainer ac = attributes.computeIfAbsent(subject, t -> {
        // Add new container when first property is discovered
        AttributesContainer a = new AttributesContainer(new ArrayList<>());
        this.builder.attributes(a);
        return a;
    });

    // LinkedHashMap to make it is sorted for the ease of testing
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("key", name);
    map.put("value", attrs.get("value"));
    ac.attributes().add(map);
}

To the best of my knowledge, map cannot be easily avoided. The ac and attrs can be inlined, but the former would hurt readability and the latter will introduce code duplicity (that I would expect sonar to also complain about).
Do I miss something, are those legit smells? If not, is here a way to relax this check to focus on more trivial cases?
I prefer not to turn this check off, as it can find real smells. Also, I do not want to spoil my code with countless //NOSONAR comments.

Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61798083/139985

@StephenC, I see this using sonar-scanner against hosted sonar running 10.4. The Java version in maven compiler plugin and the one running the sonar-scanner are both 17. Not sure if relevant, but Intellij IDEA with sonar plugin does not flag this (using java 17 as well).
